# Javascript: split time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to format a variable value that contains time data and is like the following `00:38:51` or `00:00:59` or `01:25:59`

I need to format it like `25m59s` or with hour accordingly `1h25m59s` `0m59s`

I am doing some reading on splits and I have made a start but I am getting confused.

> Syntax
>   Split(expression[,delimiter[,count[,compare]]])

```
time = "00:38:51"
timeArray = time.split(":",-1)
document.write(timeArray[0]);
```

**Update**

I created my own function, I am not sure if this is a good way to do it also;

```
function formatTime(a) {
    var time = a.split(":");
    var hours = parseInt(time[0], 10);
    var minutes = parseInt(time[1], 10);
    var seconds = parseInt(time[2], 10);
    var x = document.getElementById("time");
    x.innerHTML = hours + "h" + minutes + "m" + seconds + "s"
}

myTime = "00:38:51";
formatTime(myTime);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/V64dJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it!

```
function a(time) {
    var t = time.split(':'),
        s = ['h', 'm', 's'],
        i = 0;
    for(; i < t.length; i ++) {
        t[i] = parseInt(t[i]) == 0 ? '' : parseInt(t[i]) + s[i + s.length - t.length];
    }
    return t.join('');
}
```

<kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cw6eS/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for your code and review my function as I am new to js

Answer (score 2):

Try with `RegExp`

```
var arr = ["00:38:51","00:00:59","01:25:59"]; // created array due to demonstration
var reg = /(\d+):(\d+):(\d)/, ret = []; // RegExp and result variable declaration

arr.forEach(function(v){
    ret = reg.exec(v);
    console.log(parseInt(ret[1]) + "h" + parseInt(ret[2]) + "m" + parseInt(ret[3]) + "s"); // 0h38m5s, 0h0m5s, 1h25m5s
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ackG2/1/)</kbd>

**NOTE:** Using `parseInt` function during displaying results due to avoid printing `00` instead of `0`

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for your code and review my function as I am new to js

Comment: @J.D Fiddle is posted as well below the code. Anyways here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/ackG2/1/